# I was performing array rotation but getting incorrect output. anyone can tell me what is wrong with the code below?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main(){
     int n,i;
     cin >> n; 
     int arr[n];
     for (i = 0; i < n;i++)
         cin >> arr[i];

     int temp = arr[n - 1];
     for (i = 0; i < n - 1;i++){
         arr[i + 1] = arr[i];

     }
     for (i = 0; i < n;i++)
         cout << arr[i];

         return 0;
 }
```

above is my code and i wanna know what is wrong in this rotation logic. the output of the above code is here[image]

Comment: what is the use of `d`?

Comment: d = number of rotations performed

Comment: and where have you used it above?

Comment: sorry pal my logic was incorrect so i decided to just perform only one rotation and hence not used it.

Comment: Well that is because, when you do: `arr[i+1]=arr[i]`, you made your array values as one. You could've maybe rotates it using another temporary array

Comment: but the value of i keeps changing ...

Comment: have a look at my answer mate

Answer (score 7):

There are various issues here

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int arr[n];
```

This is not allowed. You can't have a dynamic sized array. You should use a vector instead.

In this code

```
int temp = arr[n - 1];
for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
   arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
```

You are increasing the index i, but modifying the *previous* array element. This will in effect copy the first element to the rest of the array.
(Also, prefer pre-increment for the loop variable).

Also, you are not writing temp to the first position.

It might be best to use rotate

```
std::rotate(a, a + n - 1, a + n);
```

If you absolutely must write the loop yourself, then you need to iterate in reverse order

```
int temp = arr[n - 1];
for (i = n - 1; i > 0 ; --i)
   arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
arr[0] = temp;
```

Comment: I think it is a competitive programming question and maybe using STL won't be the right approach.

Comment: @rasengan__ You mean homework? In competitive programming `std::rotate` is definitely the best way. Also, the STL is not the C++ standard library.

Answer (score 1):

In your code,

```
for (i = 0; i < n - 1;i++){
     arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
```

Here, the array values get set to the value of the first element every time and hence your output is `11111`.
To explain this further, lets say your array was `arr[3]={1,2,3}`.
Now, on first iteration,
`arr[1]=arr[0]` *i.e.* array is {1,1,3}.
In the second iteration,
`arr[2]=arr[1]` *i.e.* array is {1,1,1}.

Hence this explains this output.

The way to correct this would be to introduce a temporary array which takes in the shifted array and then copy back that array into the original one.

So, the code will be like,

```
   for(i = 0; i < n - 1;i++)
       temp[i] = arr[i+1];
   temp[n-1] = arr[0];

   for(i = 0; i < n - 1;i++)
       a[i]=temp[i];
```